# Windows Azure Powershell - installation error

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have just installed Windows Azure PowerShell by following this post
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

I see the following message when I open the PowerShell, do you know how to fix this:

```
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\' because it does not
exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\'; Impo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...werShell\Azure\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Import-Module : The specified module '.\Azure.psd1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:77
+ cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\'; Impo ...
+                                                                             ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\Azure.psd1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Azure\welcome.txt'
because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:105
+ ...  .\Azure.psd1; Get-Content .\welcome.txt; $VerbosePreference="Continue"; cd 'C:\ ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\ProgramData\...ure\welcome.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

PS C:\>
```

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1.
I installed Windows Azure Powershell via WebPI.

Do you know why the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\" is not created during the installation?

[image]

Comment: What is your Operating system, version and service pack version if any?

Comment: There are also 2 options for Installing Azure PowerShell in the doc you referenced. Are you Installing Azure PowerShell from WebPI or Installing Azure PowerShell from the PowerShell Gallery?

Comment: I use Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1. I installed Windows Azure Powershell via WebPI

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you have to run as admin.

Second click on powershell, and click on run as administrator.

Comment: I've run as administrator but still seeing the same error. I wonder why the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\" is not created during the installation.